# How to detect mysql signal from bash

Tags: mysql, bash, signals

I have sql file that signals error code if an assertion fails.

Is there a way I can check from bash if sql file runs without any signal?

I tried doing as below but it always prints OK.

```
mysql -u root -pPASS "DB_NAME" < "SQL_FILE_NAME.sql"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo FAIL
fi
```

MySQL script looks like this:

```
create procedure check
  ...
  if (@noData) then
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = message;
  end if;
  ...
end;$
call check();
```

Comment: It's probably a lot more reliable to write a small, thin wrapper in Perl, Python, Ruby, Node.js, in *anything* that has a direct MySQL driver, instead of using the extremely limited `mysql` command-line tool.

Comment: @tadman I will do that.